# Repairing a Large MyISAM Datafile

Tags: mysql, myisam, corruption, repair

I have a 54GB myisam file which reports a corrupt index file. Attempting to repair the file takes too long and stops running midway. What is the fastest way to repair this file and ensure it completes?

Comment: "stops running"... with a message?  Have you considered dropping and recreating the index?

Comment: And then switch to InnoDB so that system crashes will not corrupt the indexes.

Comment: To be frank it is a fwded question. I will get more details. But from first inquiry the process simply stops at between 20 and 30 GB out of 54. I will also post the methods my colleagues have tried

Comment: Below is the error from the last attempt ------------------------------------

Comment: - Fixing index 1
myisamchk: Can't get stat of 'E:\MySQL\Data\data\eng_helpdesk\eng_file_chunk.MYD
' (Errcode: 0 - No error)
myisamchk: error: 0 when fixing table
MyISAM-table 'E:\MySQL\Data\data\eng_helpdesk\eng_file_chunk' is not fixed because of errors
Try fixing it by using the --safe-recover (-o), the --force (-f) option or by not using the --quick (-q) flag

Comment: We seem to have found a possible solution at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69839. We are attempting

Comment: Hi Kenneth, could you add the comments you have made and **edit** your original post so that all your details are in the topic question, that makes it easier for everyone to read. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally resolved this problem by using the 5.1 version of myisamchk. It appears the 5.6 version has a bug related to inability to repair files larger than 4G.

REF: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69839